# NFS root file system

Tags: nfs

I am trying to get a remote root (and boot) NFS filesystem working correctly and I am hitting the limits of my knowledge. I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction.

**Server**

Both TFTP and NFS are served from a Linksys WRT 1900 ACS router running OpenWRT 19.07. This device also has an external SSD which is used as an overlay root file system.

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/extroot_configuration.

Each client has a root system file in this directory (Ubuntu 21.04)

`/nfs/exports/tftp/`

and a boot directory under

`/tftp/tftpboot/`

And here is the contents of /etc/exports:

`/overlay/upper/nfs/exports/ *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash) /overlay/upper/tftp/tftpboot/ *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)`

If i do not add the /overlay/upper/ prefix then I can't mount the exported directory

**Clients**

Clients successfully PXE boot and load the operating system (Ubuntu 21.04), I can log in, SSH etc. However this is not without seeing errors during boot up, or if I try to do an apt-get upgrade.

The first error I see during boot up is this:

`[Failed] Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File System`

then later I see

`[Failed] Failed to mount /boot`

yet once logged in /boot appears to be mounted.

Here is the fstab from a client

`10.1.0.1:/overlay/upper/nfs/exports/tftp/68fe97e5   /       nfs     defaults,_netdev,nfsvers=4.1,proto=tcp   0  0`

`10.1.0.1:/overlay/upper/tftp/tftpboot/68fe97e5      /boot   nfs     defaults,_netdev,nfsvers=4.1,proto=tcp   0  0`

`tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults    0   0`

`tmpfs   /var/tmp    tmpfs   defaults    0   0`

`tmpfs   /var/run    tmpfs   defaults    0   0`

(sorry about formatting)

And /boot/cmdline.txt

`net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=10.1.0.1:/overlay/upper/nfs/exports/tftp/68fe97e5,tcp ip=dhcp elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc rw cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory`

When I look at systemctl systemd-remount-fs.service I see this line

`May 27 15:10:08 rdg-clust-01 systemd-remount-fs[317]: mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified`

Can anyone point out which option I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Look at how this works in KickStart, JumpStart or the old RoboInstaller. The miniroot kernel image is served by TFTP and the file system is served by NFS. This is also how diskless UNIX clients worked in the old days.
I'm pretty sure you can't serve an entire filesystem with TFTP. It's just not how the protocol is designed.

There are a number of online documents that can help guide you to a successful diskless system configuration:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_storage_devices/setting-up-a-remote-diskless-system_managing-storage-devices

https://www.xmodulo.com/diskless-boot-linux-machine.html

http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/ldp/en/Diskless-root-NFS-HOWTO/Diskless-root-NFS-HOWTO.pdf

Comment: The file system is served over NFS, I just misnamed a directory. As I said in the OP it works, it boots. It is just complaining saying I have a setting wrong